# A proof about period length

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, decimal-expansion, fermat-numbers

In this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html

I found the following result:

$2^{2^{k}}+1$ is a Fermat prime if and only if the period length of $1/(2^{2^{k}}+1)$ is $2^{2^{k}}$.

I am asking where I can find this proof.

Comment: Presumably, the result is proven in one of the references at the bottom of the page.  Probably *Robinson, R. M. "Mersenne and Fermat Numbers." Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 5, 842-846, 1954*

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: In that paper, only numerics, no proofs.

Comment: That's surprising, too bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all : The statement is not true for $k=0$ and $k=1$. But for $k>1$ there is a proof which however needs some advanced number theoretical tools.

The period length of $1/N$ for some positive integer $N$ coprime to $10$ is equal to $$ord_{10}(N)$$ which is equal to the smallest positive integer $u$ such that $$10^u\equiv 1\mod N$$ holds.

A Fermat number (let us call it $P$) larger than $5$ is coprime to $10$. What we have to show is that we have

> $ord_{10}(P)=P-1$ if and only if $P$ is prime.

First suppose that $P$ is prime. Then, we have $$10^{P-1}\equiv 1\mod P$$ because of Fermat's little theorem and because of Euler's criterion we have 
$$10^{(P-1)/2}\equiv \left(\frac{10}{P}\right)\mod P$$ 
where () denotes the Legendre-symbol.
Since $k>1$ , $P$ is of the form $8k+1$ , hence $2$ is a quadratic residue mod P.
$P$ must also be of the form $5k+2$, hence $5$ is not a quadratic residue mod P.
Hence $10$ is not a quadratic residue mod P and we get $ord_{10}(P)=P-1$

If we have $ord_{10}(P)=P-1$ , we can immediately conclude that $P$ is prime (this is not only true for Fermat numbers). This finishes the desired proof.

Comment: How can we conclude that $P$ is prime if we have $ord_{10}(P)=P-1$? I see no trivial proof here

Comment: For instance, how can we exclude the possibility that $10$ is a [Fermat liar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_primality_test)?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom If $k$ is the order of $10$ modulo $p$ , then every prime factor of $p$ must have the form $k\cdot m+1$ , hence $p$ must be prime , if $k=p-1$. Another possibility would be : The order divides $\varphi(P)$ , therefore we must have $\varphi(P)=P-1$ , which implies that $P$ is prime.

Comment: Great, thank you.